# Ошибка 404 при GET-запросе | TELEGRAM

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, request

Здравсвуйте!

Вот запрос : `https://api.telegram.org/bot156XXXX5:AAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXNno/messages.deletehistory?peer=5244XX57X&max_id=1000`

Ответ: `{"ok":false,"error_code":404,"description":"Not Found"}`

Токен перепроверял ,метод пробовал вызывать как messages.deletehistory и deletehistory - ничего не помогает. Гуглил,но конкретно этой проблемы не нашёл.

В чём ошибка?

Юрлы: [messages.deleteHistory](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.deleteHistory)
[telegram api methods](https://core.telegram.org/methods)

Comment: Нет возможности проверить, но, как минимум, у вас deleteHistory должно быть, а не deletehistory.

Comment: Пробовал.Сейчас еще раз перепроверил - никак не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде бы вот в чем ошибка: **вызывал методы клиента,а не бота.**

Вот апишка ботов: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api